# Issue inserting Oracle Blob content into another record using Java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am working on proof of concept to read a blob content from Oracle, manipulate it and then insert back as new record using Java. Currently, I am trying to just read and then write back blob content to Oracle but facing issues. I am able to write back but looks like the file is not getting inserted completely.

**Error when trying to view/download Blob via SQL developer**

[image: Error]

**Code used to read and write back**

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
sql = "SELECT DOC_ID, NAME, BLOB_CONTENT FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE DOC_ID = " + String.valueOf(docid);

ResultSet rs_docs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs_docs.next()) {



Show_Message("Conversion sub process started ...");
doc_name = rs_docs.getString("name");
Blob ib = rs_docs.getBlob("blob_content");


Show_Message("Uploading converted pdf to database ... ");
InputStream input = ib.getBinaryStream();
String filename = doc_name;

CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("begin INSERT INTO DOCUMENTS(NAME, BLOB_CONTENT) VALUES(?,?) RETURNING DOC_ID INTO ?; end;");
callableStatement.setString(1, filename);
callableStatement.setBinaryStream(2, input, input.available());
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.executeQuery();
docid = callableStatement.getInt(3);
callableStatement.close();

Show_Message("New record created, doc # " + String.valueOf(docid));
Show_Message("Conversion Process completed!!!");

}
stmt.close();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
rs_docs.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Connection.prepareCall()` is for creating a `Statement` that calls a stored procedure.  If you want to do that then you should define an SP in the database, outside the scope of this method, and call it by name via your [`Callable`]`Statement`.  But if the only point is to get the DOC_ID assigned to the new row, then there are other ways, such as `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`.
2. Do not use `InputStream.available()` to determine the size of the blob.  "Available" means the number of bytes readable *without blocking*, *right now*, and it is allowed to be an arbitrarily inaccurate underestimate -- even zero.  It is not a reliable measure of the total number of bytes that may eventually be readable from the stream.  Instead, use the `Blob`'s `length()` method.

Comment: Thank you, John. Using blob's length instead of input.available() worked.